# Error message "using openfig" with Matlab 2018b and Octave

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a [teaching tutorial on Fourier space in MRI image generation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3097694/), and consistently getting the following error:

> Error using openfig
>
> Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in k_space_tutorial (line 20)
>        fig = openfig(mfilename, 'reuse')

[image]

I have made sure that the folder with the code and related files is in the directory:

```
>> isdir('k_Space_tutorial_David_Moratal')

ans =

  logical
1
```

and in the path:

```
>> path

        MATLABPATH

    C:\Users\Myname\Documents\MATLAB
```

These are the contents of the directory:

```
>> dir

.                             half_fov.m                    openfig.m                     
..                            image_test.bmp                rectangular_matrix.m          
README.txt                    imatge_i_espai_k_originals.m  replay_pid10644.log           
add_awgnoise.m                k_space_tutorial.fig          replay_pid11732.log           
filtre_pas_alt.m              k_space_tutorial.m            replay_pid13344.log           
filtre_pas_baix.m             modaldlg.fig                  
half_fourier_fe.m             modaldlg.m                    
half_fourier_pe.m             motion_artifacts.m
```

---

Results of the debugger:

[image]

Comment: Did you run the script in the debugger?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm used to Rstats and Python, so I'm winging it with Matlab, but I ran "Analyze Code" in the Matlab IDE, returning no suggestions or errors for line 20 of "k_space_tutorial.m". Not sure that this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Type `dbstop if error` at the MATLAB command prompt. Alternatively, open the script in the editor and click on the left margin to set a debugger breakpoint. Then run the script.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you, I just ran it, and posted the results at the end of the OP. Is there anything you can conclude from it?

Comment: When at that break point, type `which openfig`. Also check the type and contents of of `mfilename`, see if that is fishy.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Seems legit... I see the file in the folder: `K>> which openfig
C:\Users\Antoni\Documents\MATLAB\k_Space_tutorial_David_Moratal\openfig.m`. It is also a file in the OP within the results `>>dir`.

Comment: Try deleting the`openfig.m` file in the local directory. It is shadowing (hiding) the function that comes with MATLAB, and which does accept two input arguments. (My phone only shows the first column of the `dir` output, I didn’t realize I could scroll that block horizontally to see more files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openfig` is a function that comes with MATLAB, and according to [its documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html), the syntax used is correct.

One of the possible reasons for a function being called correctly but leading to an error is that a different function is called inadvertently. This happens when a different function with the same name shadows (hides) the original function. An M-file in the current directory, or in an earlier directory on the path, with the same name will cause this.

Typing `which openfig` at the MATLAB command prompt will tell you what function is called when that name is used.

In this case, there is an M-file in the current directory with the same name. Deleting this file (or renaming it) will solve the problem.